# Kura source code maven build failed with jdk:jdk.dio:jar:1.0.1 not found

Tags: java, eclipse, iot

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Java 7, have installed Rasperry Pi, have also setup the kura eclipse workspace. Now I want to use the Kura source code to start the sample application.

I followed the Eclipse Kura [getting started guide here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Kura/Getting_Started#Raspberry-Pi)

```
but when i ran `mvn clean install` in the kura/target-platform directory, 
it failed with the following message:

[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] target-platform .................................... SUCCESS [  0.147 s]
[INFO] Java API for working with Human Interface USB Devices (HID) SUCCESS [  1.832 s]
[INFO] javax.usb API from javax-usb ....................... SUCCESS [  0.226 s]
[INFO] javax.usb Common from javax-usb .................... SUCCESS [  0.239 s]
[INFO] javax.usb Linux implementation from javax-usb ...... SUCCESS [  0.190 s]
[INFO] Serial Device based on SODA DK comm ................ SUCCESS [  0.483 s]
[INFO] p2-repo-common ..................................... FAILURE [  0.491 s]
[INFO] p2-repo-equinox_3.8.1 .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.008 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-14T18:05:23+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/427M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:copy (copy-dio-bundle-for-publishing) on project p2-repo-common: Unable to find artifact. Could not find artifact jdk:jdk.dio:jar:1.0.1 in nexus-releases (http://192.168.0.119:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=jdk -DartifactId=jdk.dio -Dversion=1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=jdk -DartifactId=jdk.dio -Dversion=1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] jdk:jdk.dio:jar:1.0.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] nexus-releases (http://192.168.0.119:8081/nexus/content/groups/public, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :p2-repo-common
```

It is complaining not finding artifact `jdk:jdk.dio:jar:1.0.1` which is provided in Java ME as far as I know.  Do I need to install anything first before building the Kura source code?

Answer (score 0):

The jdk.dio artifact is available in the "Add-ons" repo provided by Eurotech at https://raw.github.com/eurotech/kura_addons/mvn-repo

It looks like you may have a custom Maven settings file that causes everything to be searched in your local Nexus? (http://192.168.0.119:8081)

HTH.